# Python: Trying to create a recursive function that checks if the text I entered is a palidrome

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**Edit: Note: I am supposed to ignore any characters that are NOT a part of the alphabet.**

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    '''
    A Recursive Function that returns True if the parameter, text, is a palindrome, False if not.
    Ignores capitalization, punctuation, and spaces.

    text: a String
    returns True or False
    '''
    text = list(text)
    if len(text) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        if text[0] == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]:
            if text[-1] == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]:
                if text[0].lower() == text[-1].lower():
                    text.remove(text[0])
                    text.remove(text[-1])
                    return is_palindrome(text)
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                text.remove(text[-1])
                return is_palindrome(text)
        else:
            text.remove(text[0])
            return is_palindrome(text)
```

I tried debugging it by entering a print statement of the "text" variable by doing print(text) before the "if" statement.

These are the results I get if I try the test case, is_palindrome("aabbcc")

```
aabbcc
['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
['b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'c']
['c', 'c']
['c']
[]
```

So it seems to only be removing the first item from the list every time by skipping to "text.remove(text[0])" in the very last else statement.

How can I fix this? Thoughts?

Comment: Are you comparing a single array item to an entire array?  Try using the equivalent of an in check when comparing.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is within comparing the single item to an entire array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed comparing a character to a whole list of characters - which is going to fail immediately.

If you must write your own code:

```
def is_ascii(c):
  # yes, python allows you to write it like this:
  return ('a' <= c <='z') or ('A' <= c <='Z')
```

Also, a `string` doesn't need to be converted to `list`:

```
def is_palindrome(text):
  # your condition for palindrome was also wrong:
  #  "foof" would end up with len(text)==0
  #  "pap" is also palindrome and ends up with len(text)==1
  if len(text)<2:
    return True

  # you don't have to modify the text before passing it to the next iteration
  # (uses Python `slicing`)
  if not is_ascii(text[0]):
    return is_palindrome(text[1:])
  if not is_ascii(text[-1]):
    return is_palindrome(text[:-1])
  # both end characters are ascii
  if text[0].lower()==text[1].lower():
    # recurse with remaining characters
    return is_palindrome(text[1:-1])
  # not a palindrome
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for equality with a list of strings:

You're checking if a singe character is equivalent to a list of characters in the line:

```
if text[0] == ['A', ....]
```

It's not passing this condition and then going to your else statement removing the first item.

You should be checking

```
if text[0] in ['A', ''']
```

Although you could import string and just check if `text[0]` in string.ascii to simplify your code some, or make the list a variable so you don't have to repeat it twice.

Even simpler, use `if text[0].isalpha()`

Comment: Alright. That works for the test case,

is_palindrome("artichoke") ----> False

But when I try

is_palindrome("Live not on evil")

It gives me a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: or use `if text[0].isalpha()`

Comment: Good point, `isalpha` is the way to go here much simpler. Completely missed that.

Comment: Thanks!    isalpha makes it even better!

But why is it telling me that the list index is out of range?